# Sonar global settings disappeared

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-4.0

The global settings options doesnt seem to available anymore. Im logged in as admin and im using Sonarqube 4.0. I did a restore of Sonar from the past working state, but still that doesn't work as well. May be something changed on DB. Any suggestions how to make the settings button re-appear.

Thanks,
Manny!
[Screen shot of sonar and admin login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvv4A.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such change can't be done in the DB unless you manually did that yourself... (either when running a SQL script or through the UI)

Now you have to update the DB manually to restore the admin role to the admin user. Take a look a the "GROUPS_USERS" table: you should have an entry that links the "admin" user to the "admin" role. Usually, this is row is "1, 1". If such a row does not exist, just add it with an INSERT SQL query.

Comment: I wasnt able to find the root cause. But i did fix it with based on your suggestion